# How to change configuration file during the deployment in git without having two repositories

Tags: git, webpack, gruntjs, grafana

I am using Grafana project for my dashboards. I have to do 2 Grafana deployments with slight changes like titles, images, etc. Previously I had 2 repositories because of this. Now I have created 2 configuration files which are json and included the changes to that. So now I am reading this json to get the correct values to replace titles, images and stuff. This is done by a custom service I wrote in the Grafana.

My 2 configuration file names are as follows;

> grafana.productA.config.json
>
> grafana.productB.config.json

I am using CI/CD in Gitlab for deployments. What I want to do is to select and rename the correct configuration file to **grafana.prod.config.json** and bundle this file with the Grafana build. Can anyone give me an idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Many [PaaS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_as_a_service) prefer configuration via environment variables because it's easy and straightforward, and all languages support them out of the box. In Go, you may simply call [`os.Getenv()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Getenv) to get the value of an environment variable.

The environment like `DEV` or `PROD` along with some parameters are usually provided via environment variables to the app, so often there is no need for a config file. If there is an extensive configuration, that itself (if not too big) could also be in an environment variable, e.g. in a base64-encoded form.

If it is unfeasible to put the config file in an environment variable, put its name into an env var, e.g. `CONFIG_FILE=grafana.productA.config.json` for dev / CI purposes, and set `CONFIG_FILE=grafana.productB.config.json` in your production server. So your app can load the appropriate config file.

If the config contains sensitive information (like passwords or private keys), "outsource" those into environment variables which of course may be different in each of your environments (like dev, CI, prod).

Comment: Grafana has a .ini file for configurations. If I want to override the default values, I have to create a cutom.ini file and override the defaults but it doesn't say anything about adding any new custom configurations. Is this the env file you are talking about?

Comment: @simplelenz You wrote in your question: _" I am reading this json to get the correct values..."_. You may use environment variables to decide which JSON file to read.